# Using Arduino with Unity (Arduino Nano 33 IoT)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino, gyroscope

I'm using Unity for a simple game. My paddle can only move up and down.
I actually use Vectors for moving paddle thanks to key up and down with my laptop.
I have an arduino Nano 33 IoT connected in usb and I want to know if it's possible to get data (gyroscope) from the arduino directly with Unity?

I don't find good tutorials to do that... And I would be very happy to move my paddle thanks to this arduino without my computer's keys.

I read the documentation, I found that I have to use the collection "*System.IO.Ports;*", specify the COM Port I use, positions in x, y & z for the gyroscope...

Here is the code for moving player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float topBounds = 8.3f;
    public float bottomBounds = -8.3f;
    public Vector2 startingPosition = new Vector2(-13.0f, 0.0f);

    [Space]
    [Header("Game")]
    [SerializeField] private Game game;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.localPosition = startingPosition;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (game.gameState == Game.GameState.Playing)
        {
            CheckUserInput();
        }
        
    }

    void CheckUserInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {

            if (transform.localPosition.y >= topBounds)
            {
                transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, topBounds, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.localPosition += Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            }

        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {

            if (transform.localPosition.y <= bottomBounds)
            {
                transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, bottomBounds, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.localPosition += Vector3.down * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've never used unity but with a little research i found this article that shows you how to connect to a serial port using a unity app.
https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/10/07/how-to-integrate-arduino-with-unity/

The second thing you need is to make a arduino application that writes a string of your coordinates too a serialport. There are plenty of tutorials about that.
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Aritro/getting-started-with-imu-6-dof-motion-sensor-96e066

Finally in your unity program you just have to parse your string and use it as an input. I wish you luck.